# In semi-overlapped bubble hide behind bubble content upto hidden part in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

I am having one problem in highchart's bubble chart.

In my code when my two bubble's series data comes to semi-overlapping condition, the behind bubble series text is not get hidden after giving z-index.

I have useHTML as true also.

Reference image
[image]

After searching so many topics & websites, i got stuck here.
Any reference or example is appreciated.

Regards,
Swapnil

Comment: if you have a working fiddle, please share it. It would help to analyse better to give a better solution

Comment: As strikes said, pleae replaice your example as live demo (i.e on jsfiddle.net).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Sopo/EPvD7/

Answer (score 1):

When using useHTML, you should be aware that elements are rendered as true HTML. Meanwhile all elements on a chart are rendered as SVG/VML. It's not possible to have structure:

```
< html element z-index:10>
< svg element z-index:9>
< html element z-index:8> 
< svg element z-index:7>
```

HTML tags/element can be only under or over ALL SVG elements.

Answer (score 0):

try this, i think it will help you...

```
.blue_bubble{
z-index:1;
}

.red_bubble{
z-index:2;
}
```